# How do I breed a Current Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

There are credible reports of another hidden dragon similar to the Dodo Dragon (initially). It looks to be a water/lightning hybrid like the Plasma. Can I just use the combinations for Plasma, or is there more secret sauce?  How will I know when I've gotten one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something on the dragonvale wiki: I haven't verified it though.

[How to breed a Current Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Current_Dragon)

That is, a Water Dragon with a Lightning hybrid.

And you know you have one by checking out the [eggs and incubation time here](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Eggs).

Comment: [Here's a matrix showing the breeding combinations](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Breeding).

Answer (score 1):

It is storm and water, got it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

A mix of Love and Water have been reported as successful.

The egg will be blue with light blue lightning bolt, with a 16 hour wait.